# How do submit data from a Thymeleaf form into a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, forms, button, thymeleaf

I had a Spring MVC application that would populate data into a Monogo database from an HTML form upon clicking a submit button. I've since had to convert that into a Thymeleaf template with Spring Boot, but I'm a little overwhelmed on how to properly get it to work.

This is my form:

```js
alert('JS is linked to page!');

function Article(id = 1, title = "", authors="", content = "", genre = "", date = 1497484623) {
    console.log("JavaScript file loaded successfully");
    var self = this;
    self.Id = id;
    self.Title = title;
    self.Authors = authors;
    self.Content = content;
    self.Genre = genre;
    self.Date = date;
    self.Save = function() {
        var settings = {
            url: 'http://localhost/program/submit',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
              beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            }
        };
        var myData = {
   "Id" : self.Id,
            "Title": self.Title,
            "Authors": self.Authors,
            "Content": self.Content,
            "Genre": self.Genre,
            "Date": self.Date
        };
        settings.data = myData;
 
        $.ajax(settings).done(function(article) {
         var myArticle = new Article(article.Id, article.Title, article.Authors,
                article.Content, article.Genre, article.Date);
        });
    };
}



function addArticle(Article) {
    alert('addArticle Activated');
    var settings = {
        url: 'http://localhost/program/submit',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
          beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            }
    };
    var myData = {  
  "Title": Article.Title,     
  "Authors" : Article.Authors,
  "Content": Article.Content,
  "Genre" : Article.Genre,
  "Date": Article.Date 
    };
    settings.data = myData;
 
    $.ajax(settings).done(function(Article) {
        var myArticle = new Article(article.Id, article.Title, article.Authors, article.Content,
            article.Genre, article.Date);
        console.log("Article Created");
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

 
    $(document).on("submit", "#addArticle", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            alert('submit Activated');
        var title, authors, genre, content;
        title = $("#Title").val();
        director = $("#Authors").val();
        rating = $("#Genre").val();
        notes = $("#Content").val();
        var myArticle = new Article(0, title, authors, genre, content, 1497484623);
        alert(myArticle.Title);
        addArticle(myArticle);
        $("#add-article")[0].reset();
        $("#title").focus();
 
    });

});
```

```html
<form action="@{/addArticle}" th:object="${addArticle}" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id"/>
    <input type="text" id="title" name="title"/>
    <label for="title">Title </label>
    <input type="text" id="authors" name="authors"/>
    <label for="authors">Author(s) </label>
    <input type="text" id="genre" name="genre"/>
    <label for="genre">Genre </label>
    <input type="text" id="content" name="content"/>
    <label for="content">Content </label>
    <button type="button" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

</form>
```

**What I have tried**

1. I've tried reading the documentation on Thymeleaf
2. I've tried browsing StackOverflow, but the examples aren't explained well enough and are still confusing. I see things like this:

> ```
>  th:onclick="|upload('${command['class'].simpleName}', '${variable}')|"
> ```

The thing is that I don't just want to copy code without understanding what I'm doing. If anyone could help, I would be very grateful.